# Lucky Sevens Game (beginner)

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting the program to repeat the loop until `mypot != 0`. The object of the program is to ask user for amount of money to put in the pot, and ask user to roll dice until `mypot !=0`

```
import random

mypot = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you want in the pot: "))
diceroll1  = random.randint(1, 7)
diceroll2 = random.randint(1, 7)
myrole = (diceroll1 + diceroll2)
while True:
    mypot > 0
if myrole == 7:
    print("Your roll was a 7 you eaerned press enter to roll again:  ", mypot + 4)
    break
elif  myrole != 0
    print("Sorry you did not roll a 7 press enter to roll again: ", mypot - 1)
    break
elif mypot != 0:
    print("Sorry you do not have no more money in your pot")
    break
```

---

**Update:** I am having trouble getting the program to repeat the loop until `mypot == 0`

```
import random

mypot = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you want in the pot: "))
while mypot > 0:    # looping untill mypot <= 0
  dice_roll = random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7)  # rolling the dices
print(dice_roll[0], dice_roll[1])
myrole = sum(dice_roll)
if myrole == 7:
    mypot += 4    # without this you're not modifing the myrole value
    print("Your roll was a 7 you earned. Press enter to roll again:", mypot)
else:
    mypot -= 1
    print("Sorry you did not roll a 7. Press enter to roll again:", mypot)
input()   # waiting for the user to press Enter

print("Sorry, there's no more money in your pot.")
```

Comment: Fix your indentation with four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is quite strange: `elif mypot != 0` will never be cheked, beacuse either one of the previous condition will be True, so your while loop isn't also a loop at all.

To fix that you need to change:

```
elif mypot != 0:
    print "Sorry you do not have no more money in your pot"
    break
```

with:

```
if mypot != 0:
    print "Sorry you do not have no more money in your pot"
    break
```

And put this before the other ifs.

But your code seems to have other issues:

There's:

```
mypot > 0
```

Right after the `while True`, why it's not:

```
while mypot > 0:
    # ...
```

Also the value of `myrole` doesn't seem to be modified in the `while` loop, so what's that `while` non-loop doing there?

*DSM* is suggesting that you're trying to use that `while` non-loop as a switch.

I think you're trying to do something like:

```
import random

mypot = input("Please enter the amount of money you want in the pot: ")
# or as alternative:
#mypot = int(raw_input("Please enter the amount of money you want in the pot: "))
while mypot > 0:    # looping untill mypot <= 0
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7)  # rolling the dices
    print dice_roll[0], dice_roll[1]
    myrole = sum(dice_roll)
    if myrole == 7:
        mypot += 4    # without this you're not modifing the myrole value
        print "Your roll was a 7 you earned. Press enter to roll again:", mypot
    else:
        mypot -= 1
        print "Sorry you did not roll a 7. Press enter to roll again:", mypot
    raw_input()   # waiting for the user to press Enter

print "Sorry, there's no more money in your pot."
```

Comment: Actually, after fixing the syntactic errors, the while loop will *always* break.  It'll either break if the roll is a 7 in the first branch, or it'll break on the second branch.  I think the OP is using "break" here as one might in a switch statement in C, i.e. to get out of the chained ifs.

Comment: @DSM: You're right, I gave a "too quick" look at the code, thanks. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Agree with Rik - I don't see where the `mypot` variable is being modified either.

Comment: @AndreHarrisII: You are printing the new `mypot` value, but if you don't assing that value back to `mypot` its value will not change. I try to modify your example, take a look.

Comment: @RikPoggiI see my mistakes in the program now and also seeing progress. The only problem that i see is coming up with myrole

Comment: @AndreHarrisII: Yes, your code have other issues other than that. Check my example, I'va added a couple of comments to explain it a bit.

Comment: @RikPoggi one more problem and I think im done.  Pressing enter brings back Syntax error: unexpected EOF while parsing any idea for the solution?

Comment: @Andre: At wich point you get that error? Try to run my code exactly as it is (I fixed a couple of typos). If after that you still get some errors that you can't understand, update your question and include the complete traceback. (beacuse it's a little hard to tell by comment) :)

Comment: @RikPoggi: I think he's running Python 2, so his input() needs something as input.  (That doesn't match his print style, but it *would* explain the error.)

Comment: @RikPoggi my error is fixed now. The only problem is continuing the program until mypot = 0

Comment: @Andre: Are you on `python-2` or `python-3` *(as @DSM is asking)*? The code you've posted in your question is bad indented. If you ran the exact code I've posted it should work, you'll have to press enter unitll you loose all your money.

Comment: im using python 2 and when i press enter after the first roll this is the return message i get (sorry for the bad indenting but its the exact as your posting) :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andre/Desktop/my.py", line 14, in <module>
    input("Press enter")   # waiting for the user to press Enter
  File "<string>", line 0
    
   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @Andre: Then you need to use Python 2 Syntax! Meaning that `print` is a statement: hence no brackets, and [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) and [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) are different function, and you should choose which one does what you want.

Comment: @RikPoggi Ok i found my problem

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with this. First of all, since python uses what's called semantic whitespace, the indentation matters. So where you have

```
while True:
 mypot > 0
if myrole == 7:
    print("Your roll was a 7 you eaerned press enter to roll again:  ", mypot + 4)
    break
```

it's reading this as: while True, evaluate (mypot > 0). Then move on to the if statement. Your elifs should be on the same level of indentation as your if statement, as well, and you need a colon after your frist elif.

Anyway, that's probably not the biggest issue. Inside your loop, you dont have anything changing. You need to move that while True: statement up to the ilne right above diceroll1. All the code after while True: will be what executes over and over, and inside your while loop now the value of myrole isn't getting reassigned.